# Wrapper to choose between scale_x_date and scale_x_datetime

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, posixct

Since [scale_x_date](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) is for "date" and [scale_x_datetime](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) is for "POSIXct",
is it possible to have a wrapper to automatically decide which of the two to choose, since both even have the same function arguments.

Similar to this but with its arguments (the data) taken from the aestetics of my geoms:

```
scale_x_date_flex <- function(date_labels = "%B",date_breaks = "months")){

    if(any(class(DF$Date) =="POSIXct")){
        return(scale_x_datetime(date_labels = date_labels ,date_breaks = date_breaks))
    }else{
        return(scale_x_date(date_labels = date_labels ,date_breaks = date_breaks))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. But since you can't access the data of a plot when using the `+` (as far as I know) we have to use the `magrittr` pipe instead to be able to test the class of the `x` aesthetic.

## Function

```
scale_x_date_flex <- function(plot,
                              date_labels = "%B", 
                              date_breaks = "months") {

  if ("POSIXct" %in% class(plot$data[[quo_name(plot$mapping$x)]])) {
    message("scale_x_datetime")
    return(plot + scale_x_datetime(date_labels = date_labels, date_breaks = date_breaks))
  } else {
    message("scale_x_date")
    return(plot + scale_x_date(date_labels = date_labels, date_breaks = date_breaks))
  }

}
```

## Example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

last_month_date <- Sys.Date() - 0:29
last_day_time <- Sys.time() - 0:29 * (60 * 60)

df <- data.frame(
  date = last_month_date,
  time = last_day_time,
  price = runif(30)
)


base_d <- ggplot(df, aes(date, price)) +
  geom_line()

base_t <- ggplot(df, aes(time, price)) +
  geom_line()



base_d %>% scale_x_date_flex(date_labels = "%d", date_breaks = "5 days")
#> scale_x_date
```

[image]

```
base_t %>% scale_x_date_flex(date_labels = "%d %H:%M", date_breaks = "5 hour")
#> scale_x_datetime
```

[image]

But you can still use it in the middle of a `ggplot` command chain. So this will work:

```
base_d %>% scale_x_date_flex(date_labels = "%d", date_breaks = "5 days") + theme_bw()
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>